# Using "use" in PHP version < 5.3

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP-based web-application. The version of PHP running is 5.2.x! I have a function `play` in the program, as well as an array called `$study`, defined outside `play`, containing a few elements.

```
function play( $games, $time ) {
//Do something here 
$lol = array_search(strtolower($games), array_map('strtolower', $study['somevar']));
}
```

Now the point here is I am calling `play()` elsewhere in my code but as you can see I reference `$study['somevar']` but the function takes only two arguments: `$games` & `$time` so there is no way to reference $study['somevar']. I know sometimes in PHP this also works

```
function play($games, $time) use ($study){
  //do something
}
```

But when i try to run using this `use` syntax in PHP 5.2 than it gives error. So, How can I possibly do this? Any ideas?

Edit 1:

So, this is what Array of $study prints out (which i tried outside function)

```
echo $study['somevar'] : It prints out Array (English word "Array")
echo $study['somevar'][0] : It prints out blahblah (0th element)
echo $study['somevar'][1] : It prints out OKoK (1st element)
```

In simple words , by using var_dump($study) i got

```
["somevar"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "blahblah"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "OKoK"
```

There is no 2nd Element in study -> somevar .. So, only two (0th and 1st)

Now, basically I want to use this Array to search it with $games inside the function `play` . So, for that inside the function; as you can see above in pseudo code i have used

`array_search(strtolower($games), a second element)`

Now this Second element inside array_search, i want all the elements of the array $study (i.e blahblah, OKoK) to be converted to lower case, so that i could match easily using `array_search` method. Hence, i used the logic to `array_map('strtolower', $study['somevar'])` ..

and placed it into `array_search` method like :

`$lol = array_search(strtolower($games), array_map('strtolower', $study['somevar']));`

Now, In further code i pass some values in function `play('OkOk', 10);` and in this the OKOK should match into our hard-coded $study array as the element 1 contains that key . This is the logic. But i get error like

```
array_map() Argument #2 should be an array in ..........
array_search() [<a href='function.array-search'>function.array-search</a>]: Wrong datatype for second argument in .........
```

Comment: Still error @RyanVincent `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in <somepath>` & `array_search():  Wrong datatype for second argument in <somepath>`

Comment: @RyanVincent When printing study['somevar'][0] outside the function it gives output well.

Comment: @RyanVincent Brother, I have updated the Question with complete steps. Kindly re-look

Comment: One more thing additional to question edit, When i used `global $study;` inside the function play & also tried to do var_dump($study); again **inside** the function than it gives NULL . So, it means the logic of global didn't worked (Maybe)

Comment: "The version of PHP running is 5.2.x!" -- find a better web host, like *now*. PHP 5.2 went end-of-life over five years ago.

Comment: Agreed @duskwuff . Thanks for the suggestion, i would change the host. But i would like to enumerate the possibility if such is possible on 5.2.17 :)

Comment: There is no excuse to run 5.2 in 2016. It has been dead for almost 6 years http://php.net/eol.php. The only real answer to your question is: upgrade you r php version to 7.0. Or at the very least the latest 5.6. If your host doesn't cooperate run to a sane one instead or get a cheap vps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `use` in PHP 5.2 because it was introduced in PHP 5.3 but you can use `global`:

```
function play( $games, $time ) {
    global $study;
    //Do something here 
    $lol = array_search(strtolower($games), array_map('strtolower', $study['somevar']));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't works.. I updated question with additional detail look